# And what about the beginners who receive a post ban?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I was banned from asking questions on Stack Overflow because many of my questions have a score of 0. I really think that is too much. What should the beginners do? Where should they ask their questions? Will it harm you to help the beginners?

Comment: You dont get banned for not getting any votes. Have you deleted any questions? Down votes and deleted questions factor into bans among other things.

Comment: I believe it's not due to those that got no votes, but because of those that did get downvotes, or those that were deleted.

Comment: We don't ban new users just because of it. What do you think? It has a reason someone gets banned. It's because of bad or off-topic questions.

Comment: SO has nothing against beginners. SO doesn't like bad questions -- read the help center pages and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) first.

Comment: ["I have an error and I don't know why"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801499/i-have-error-and-i-dont-know-why) - seriously? This is a pretty bad title.

Comment: I suggest reading [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) and applying the tips.

Comment: So, you've got eight questions that weren't deleted. One got -2 score, two other got closed, one at +1, and the rest are weeds. I don't think the weeds are the cause of your bans. The closures probably did contribute, however. You've also given no answers.

Comment: You are very close to the edge of the automatic ban - improve your questions (edit them and make them better, following the suggestions from the link in my previous comment would take you a long way towards that), get a few upvotes on them and you should clear the ban.

Comment: At least you're accepting answers (giving them the checkmark), which is better than leaving them to flap in the breeze.  I would definitely suggest reading the link Oded provided above to make sure your questions are well worded/constructed, and use Jan's suggestion of answering questions when possible.  The more you answer, the quicker your ban will be lifted.  In the meantime, at least try to turn your questions into better questions and maybe you'll get a few upvotes, which will also help lift your ban.

Comment: @Oded can you actually see how close a person is to the threshold, or only what can one assume from seeing deleted posts?

Comment: @JanDvorak - staff have a very detailed report available to us that breaks down the algorithm to components and shows the whole calculation.

Comment: I actually saw your questions and some are confusing (typing) or does not have a focus, are not bad questions only need to improve the way of doing issues. In the beginning all have difficulty, but that with time you learn to express yourself better. Search to see questions from other users with high reputation, it might help you to form the text of your question (this is just my opnion), Do not be discouraged. Good luck

Comment: @JanDvorak I deleted the posts becaouse I found the problem and the problem was something like I forgot to add ; or I write != where I should write == and so on. Until now 0 posts deleted by someone that not me.

Comment: @VladGincher ... in which case they shouldn't have been asked in the first place.

Answer (score 8):

You need to improve the quality of the questions you are asking in order to avoid down votes and the possibility of an automatic ban. Writing questions like "I have error and I don't know why" are a sure fire way to receive down votes. Try starting your question with the problem you are attempting to solve, what you have done thus far and what errors you are receiving, instead of the other way around.

For example, your most recent question with down votes starts "I have no idea why, but if I fill both of the fields it writes "success". It doesnt metter what I write in the fields. In the user database I have the id, username, first name, last name, email and password." This is a horrible start to a question, as we have no idea what you are talking about from the beginning.

You can find guidance on writing good questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). Once you clean up your questions, and include relevant details, you should receive more upvotes, and decrease your likelihood of a ban.

Comment: As you can see by my writing, I'm really bad in english. I doesn't have any other way to explain myself. For example, now when I'm trying to login its shows me error even that the details are true. It is not relevant to no one except me (because probably it is another stupid mistake that I don't know where it is). I also don't know how to describe the question. So what the people with the bad English should do?